# visibility behaviour disable callbacks seems not working

Tags: semantic-ui

In trying so recreate the right following menu in semantic ui site,

I put visibility on the different sections of the page
that set to active the corresponding menu entry. It works ok.

But when I simply click on the menu entries, that also triggers visibility callbacks, because the page is moving

With this set up

```
.on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var el = $($(this).attr('href'));
            $(this)
                .addClass('active')
                .siblings()
                .removeClass('active')
            ;
            $('.card-item').visibility('disableCallbacks');
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: el.offset().top});
            $('.card-item').visibility('enableCallbacks');
        });
```

I intended to go to the desired place el without triggering the visibility callbacks of all sections with visibility set, that need to be crossed to get to el, but that is a no op.

I tried also 'disable callbacks' instead of 'disableCallbacks'

I tried it manually in the console , same thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is `'disable callbacks'` as two words.

So:

`$(selector).visibility('disable callbacks')`